# HTML5 Video Tag Width/Height

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to create a video tag for use with Chrome only.  I don't always know the dimensions of the video, but I would like to have it be the size of the window.  I thought I could accomplish this by using "width=100%" and "height=100%", but I found that the built-in controls were hard to see.  I reduced height to 98%.  Most of the videos I am currently trying to play are 720p MP4's.  I tried playing a 1080p (actual dimensions being 1920x1040), and it wouldn't work (the video player acted as if my source was wrong, but I could right click and successfully download the file).  The file size was more than 3 gig, I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it.

Edit:  I also checked that the codecs were the exact same, and they are between the smaller and larger videos.

Anybody else having the same or like issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "it wouldn't work"?

Comment: The play button was disabled and the bar that shows progress was never shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to post on here now that I've fixed this issue.  The issue was the file size information is apparently at the end of normal MP4's.  For streaming, we want this information at the front of the file so the player can decide how to buffer and what-not.  Chrome must do some sort of quick file size check if it doesn't find the file size information at the beginning.  I used a program called QT-Faststart which moves the file size information to the front of the file.  Thus solving the issue.